# jquery counter stops each function

Tags: jquery, each

Im making a script that checks if there are empty fields and if so makes them red and disable a submit button. In using a counter to determine if any empty fields are found, however this stops the each function.

```
    function submitDisable(){
    $('.shipdiv input').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == ''){
    $(this).css("background-color","#ff0000");
    $(this).closest('.shipdiv').find('#button-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    counter++;
}
});
    if(counter == "0"){
    $(this).css("background-color","");
    $(this).closest('.shipdiv').find('#button-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
   }

jQuery(document).ready(submitDisable);
```

Comment out the `counter++;` and all empty fields are nicely colored red, leave it in and it stops the each loop and only the first field is red. Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `counter` defined?

Comment: counter is a global variable? BTW, i don't really understand your logic here, shouldn't you call submitDisable on submiting form instead? And please check your console for error

Comment: Could you post the HTML?  Maybe post your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: Where can i check my console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create a variable 'counter' maybe? add `var counter = 0;` in front of your functions :)

Comment: I found that yes, I was used to php where you can define a variable on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Is `counter` a global? If so, it should be set to `0` initially.

Second observation: Your comparison should be `counter === 0` rather than `counter == "0"`.

Additinally, `submitDisable()` runs only once (on the document ready event). Maybe you want it to run when a field has been edited. In this case `counter` should be local to `submitDisable()`.